# customizing Highcharts problems. New

Tags: highcharts

I have got a couple of problems with highcharts, I am using a heat map.

1. The subtitle is covered by the chart, how could I solve that?.
2. How could I set a max length for each cell? When I have got just a few elements it is really big.
3. I dont want to show any colour in the background.
4. I dont want to show the values of the cells.

Comment: This format is not suited for StackOverflow. You should stick to one problem at a time, so it is easily searchable and answerable. Also, you should try to better demonstrate your problems, as it is not always easy for others to "see what you are seeing".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set maximum size for cells Highcharts heat map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776476/set-maximum-size-for-cells-highcharts-heat-map)

Answer (score 0):

1) Looks like possibly bug, reported here: `https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3255`

2) have you tried to use [max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) parametr on axis? http://jsfiddle.net/kJpS6/3/

3) See the option http://jsfiddle.net/kJpS6/2/

4) You can disable it by xAxis [labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels)

Comment: Thanks, but.. 2) That is to show how many axis to show, not the size. 3) which one? 4) I want to disable the value of the cell, not the labels of the xAxis or yAxis

Comment: 2) you can define it in the [pixels](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPixelInterval) 3) Points has 0 value as 3 parameter 4) you can disable [datalabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled)

Comment: 2)How? I think it doesnt work for heat maps. 3) Sorry, I meant the hover colour and the borders, that soft blue. 4) That doesnt work, they are shown anyway. Thanks for answering

Comment: I have done another jsfiddle with the problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761282/highcharts-options-not-working   I also should add the size problem, if you know how to solve it would be great :)

Comment: 2) Indeed it looks like and issue, we will investigate this issue 3) So hover should not be applied? 4) For me, disabling datalbels works http://jsfiddle.net/5KKZm/2/

Comment: Yes, the only problem I have now its with 2. Thank you very much.