# Highcharts Options not working

Tags: highcharts

So, I have got this code, and when the cell value is NaN (Not a number), it is showed with the black colour, not with this one, and the tooltip with all the decimals. What am I missing?

```
plotOptions: {
  heatmap: {
        nullColor: '#3bd268',
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2,
        },
  },
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/548DQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the tooltip down to say 2 decimal points as such:

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value.toFixed(2) + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        }
```

As for your data, I would perhaps assign the data to variable first and then iterate over it detecting if it is a `string`.  Then you can assign a `null` to it to make it work correctly.
You could also in this instance fix the decimals if you so wished.

```
myData = [
        [0, 0, 10.873453],
        [0, 1, "aa"],
        [0, 2, 8],
        [0, 3, 24],
        [0, 4, 67],
        [1, 0, 92],
        [1, 1, 58] .....
        ................

for (var key in myData) {
        if (myData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(typeof (myData[key][2]) == 'string')
                myData[key][2] = null;
        }
    }

......

series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: myData, // <-- Add myData here
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none',
                    HcTextStroke: null
                }
            }
        }]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/548DQ/1/

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to show the string "unknown"? can I define a colour for it?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the `dataLabels` object and pass it a `formatter` which would only return 'unknown' for null values and then the real value for valid values.  The 'unknown' cells will automatically get the color defined in `plotMap -> nullColor` e.g. `nullColor: 'pink'` http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/548DQ/3/