# Set maximum size for cells Highcharts heat map

Tags: highcharts

I cant find the way of setting a maximum size for the cells of a heat map.

It always go for the 100% of the space, it doesnt mind if I only use this data:

```
data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],[1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48]],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJeUm/

Comment: Make your chart smaller accordingly

Comment: the whole chart? cant I define a maximum size for the cells so that would be automatically?

Comment: It would look silly to have 2 columns and then a large gap until the legend on the right?

Comment: I can put the legend in the bottom, is it possible to set maximum size of the cells then? My heat map is rendered a lot of times so I think that would solve a lot of problems

Comment: Highcharts render chart according to width/height set for container. It won't change width/height according to number of cells, sorry. Rob has right - make chart smaller. Or set higher margins in chart options.

Comment: So I will have to set that parameters dynamically, right? because my heat map can have 4 elements or 400..

Comment: Yes you will pretty much.  Since you have control over the data you can do that but I really don't think it's too bad having wide columns that fill all available space.  I wouldn't waste too much more time on it TBH.

Comment: Are you looking for properties of `series` like: `colsize` and `rowsize`? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/dJeUm/1/

Comment: I dont think so, because it leaves a gap between them, but thanks!